# How to send a broadcast to a specific set of users?

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

For example the client wants to use Urban Airship to send a push notification to users with app version 1.0 only, but not 1.1 or 1.2. They might want to remind users of an old version to update their app, without bothering users who have already updated.

Is it possible to implement? If so, how? As far as I know, there is no way to control that and all registered users will receive the broadcast message. But I just wanted to double check.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not make this, google will ban your app from the market as they do not allow anymore push notifications sent to the users for advertising another or your own app. So even if there is no way to "select" people exept if you run your own server updated by the app (you cant do it throught google platform ) dont bother to make a server for that as you will be incompatible with Google's App policy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wasn't aware of this policy before. Can you provide some links?

Comment: These should be all info you need , http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/08/23/teardown-google-pushes-major-update-to-play-developer-content-policy-kills-notification-bar-ads-for-real-this-time-and-a-lot-more/